# How to distribute the operations on a single thread to different multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, named-pipes, python-multithreading

How can I distribute the operations, say duplicate the items\actions sent in one pipe to various different pipes which can access the original pipe?

Say I have Parent thread is "Pthread", I want to link it to 4 or 5 child threads, Just like a binary tree. Any operations performed on "Pthread" should be distributed to all the child threads(Something similar to what ESB does in the SOA architecture).

[image: One to Many in Distribution in Pipe]

Like A+B should be sent in all the 5 threads\pipes at the same time and processed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MainThreadEntry  {



     public void ThreadCreationMethod()
        {
         List<Future<Object>> listOfResult = null; // listOfResult is list of Integer objects as a result of computation by different threads
         ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); // no of threads to create from main thread
         List<EachThreadComputation> list = new ArrayList<MainThreadEntry .EachThreadComputation>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             EachThreadComputation separeateComputaionInnerClass = new EachThreadComputation(1,2); // innerClass Created For Ecah Thread 1,2 parameter can be dynamic
             list.add(separeateComputaionInnerClass);
         }
         try {

             listOfResult = executor.invokeAll(list); // call on different threads with 5 separate executionpath for computation

         } catch (InterruptedException e) {

         }






        }


private class EachThreadComputation implements Callable<Object>{
          private int A;
          private int B;


          EachThreadComputation(int A,int B) {
                this.A = A;
                this.B = B;

            }


            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                   return (Integer)A+B

      }
      }}
```